# compare two vectors in c++ with template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, memcpy

I want to compare two vectors using template class.

```
vector<Msg> gExpMsg;
vector<Msg> gRevcMsg;
```

i have to use `template class;` and compare 2 `vector` using `memcmp`.
Could you please guide me in code C++.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? BTW, `memcpy()` copies, it does not compare.

Comment: sorry.. not memcpy... memcmp

Comment: template <class vector<Msg> >
Msg Validate(Msg m1, Msg m2)
{
  memcmp(); // i have to do for m1 and m2
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use STL equal or mismatch algorithms to compare two containers. In these algorithms you can give your own predicate functor if you want. Below is the link where you can find sample code
[mismatch algorithm sample](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/stl/algorithms/nonmodifying/mismatch.php)

mismatch returns the pair values which holds the differences between two containers (in your case its vector)
Here is some snippet from sample for quick view

```
//find first mismatch
pair<vector<int>::iterator,list<int>::iterator> values;
values = mismatch (coll1.begin(), coll1.end(), //first range
                      coll2.begin());    //second range
if (values.first == coll1.end()) 
  cout <<"no mismatch"<<endl;     
else
  cout <<"first mismatch: "<<*values.first<<" and "<<*values.second<<endl;
```

With predicate

```
values = mismatch (coll1.begin(), coll1.end(), //first range
                       col12. begin(),   //second range
                       less_equal<int>() )  //criterion
if (values.first == coll1.end()) 
  cout <<"always less-or-equal"<<endl;
else 
  cout <<"not less-or-equal: "<<*values.first<<" and "          
                            <<*values.second<<endl;
```